# How to make something behind without using position absolute

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a quiz app. In which users select an option based on his confidence so for that I decided to make three boxes in each option using touchable opacity and its working fine but I want to have text behind these boxes that I failed to achieve yet. Here is my code

Note: This "Style" contains style objects for the app.

```
<View style={[ Style.flexRow, Style.marginV5, Style.borderRadius20, Style.paddingDefault, Style.bgLight ]}>
 <Text>Ajax</Text>
 <TouchableOpacity style={[ Style.flex, Style.borderRight, Style.height100, Style.borderLeft ]}>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 <TouchableOpacity style={[ Style.flex, Style.borderRight, Style.height100, Style.borderLeft ]}>
 </TouchableOpacity> 
 <TouchableOpacity style={[ Style.flex, Style.borderRight, Style.height100, Style.borderLeft ]}>
 </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

[image]

One way is to do that is to make text position absolute but after that, it is impossible to change the height of the parent dynamically according to text size. Please help me to solve this issue or suggest me if you know any better solution than this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the text as `absolute`, you could put the `TouchableOpacity` boxes inside a `flex` container and set the container to `absolute` instead. This would allow the text size to control the height of the box, while allowing you to add as many boxes as you like in front of the text.

See my example here:
https://codepen.io/sungaila/pen/oQpPQq

Comment: Another problem comes in. Do you know how to make touchable opacity touchable while having an overlay of text? Because I want those block to not make text unreadable so for that I gave the text to z-index of 1 but this makes the Touchable opacity unpressable.

Comment: Try setting the CSS to `pointer-events: none` on the text, and `pointer-events: auto` on the boxes.

Comment: It doesn't make boxes to clickable because the text is always above the boxes. I want to show the text above the boxes and also make them touchable

Comment: Hmm, you might have to make a new question for this.

One hack I can think of would be to put the text back behind the boxes and set its opacity to zero (so that it still sets the height), then add a new text element inside the first `TouchableOpacity` box and set its position to absolute. The new text element will be the 'display' text, and the old text element will purely be to set the size of the box.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! that can work maybe. But I found another solution that is similar to this. I added up another View of boxes with the same absolute position. This is used to trigger actions onPress event and another one that is behind the text is used to give the borders and highlighted background and it's working fine. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can give negative margin values to other elements.

Since you have `Text` component hierarchically in the first order, you should set `TouchableOpacity's` margin to a negative value.

```
<Text>Ajax</Text>
<TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop: -100}}
```

This way, `TouchableOpacity` will move 100 unit upwards, and overlay the `Text` element.

Comment: Thanks! but This is almost the same solution as position absolute to the text. Actually, I want to have a dynamic height of parent and those bars according to the text (number of lines)